# Guardar datos de un formulario en un tabla(grid) en Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, visual-studio

este es mi primero proyecto y me recomendaron usar angular , estoy tratando de hacer un formulario en el cual capte los datos solicitados y los deje en una table(grid ) y con el boton se guarde y posteriormente continuar guardar mas Despachos en este caso , estaba todo bonito hasta que llegue a usar los ngmodel , que no entiendo como unirlo con los datos de del formulario y los de la tabla(grid), de antemano muchas gracias si pudieran ayudarme
intento rellenar los datos del formulario  y lo que tengo entendido es qe asigandndole el ngmodel a ciertas variables puedo ahorrarme el getelementbyid entonces en eso estoy estancado ,

les dejo lo que llevo en el index y el ts

```
<div class="imgRow container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="chilexpress">
               <img src="https://d31dn7nfpuwjnm.cloudfront.net/images/valoraciones/0030/0382/chilexpress-horarios-sucursales-region-metropolitana.png?1521706457"  alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="chilebox">
                <img src="https://www.chilebox.cl/comounpro/images/logo.png"
                 alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fondo  "  > 
    <div class="textTitle">
        <h1> 
            Control de Despacho
        </h1>

    </div>


    <div class="cont-texto container-fluid">
        <div class="form Formulario">
            <strong>Vuelo Master</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="Master" placeholder="Introduce numero de la Master" required class="form-control" name="vueloMaster" style="width: 49%;">
                    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cliente :</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="nomCliente" placeholder="Introduce nombre de cliente" required class="form-control" name="Cliente">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cantidad Pre-Alerta :</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="preAlerta" placeholder="Introduce Cantidad de piezas en Pre-Alerta" required class="form-control" name="qPrealerta">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cantidad Manifestado :</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="pManifiesto" placeholder="Introduce Cantidad de piezas en manifiesto" required class="form-control" name="qManifstado">
                        
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cantidad Retenido :</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="pRetenida" placeholder="Introduce Cantidad de piezas retenidas" required class="form-control" name="qRetenido">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cantidad Transferida :</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="pTransferida" placeholder="Introduce Cantidad de piezas transferidas" [(ngModel)]="cantTransferido" required class="form-control" name="qTransferido">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cantidad Despachado :</strong>
                        <input type="text" id="pDespachadas" placeholder="Introduce Cantidad de piezas despachadas" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="cantDespachado" name="qDespachada">
                        
                    </div>
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <input type="button"  class="btnGuardar" name="" value="Guardar Despacho" (click)="Guardado()">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
          <th>Vuelo Master</th>
          <th>Cliente</th> 
          <th>Cantidad Pre-Alerta</th>
          <th>Cantidad Manifiesto</th>
          <th>Retenido</th>          
          <th>Cantidad Transferida</th>          
          <th>Cantidad Despachado</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Valor</td> -->

          
            <td> 
              <input [(ngModel)]="vMaster" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoMaster}}"/>    
                    </td>   
            <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="cliente" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoCliente}}"/>    
                     </td>
            
            <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="cantPrealerta" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoPrealerta}}"/>    
                     </td>
            
            <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="cantManifestado" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoManifestado}}"/>    
                     </td>
         
            <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="cantRetenido" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoRetenido}}"/>    
                     </td>
            
            <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="cantTransferido" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoTransferido}}"/>    
                    </td>
            
            <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="cantDespachado" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{campoDespachado}}"/>    
                     </td>
            
  
  
  
            
          
          


          
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
      </table>
      
    

    




 
</div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-despacho',
  templateUrl: './despacho.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./despacho.component.scss']
})
export class DespachoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  public vMaster: string = '';
  public cliente: string = '';
  public cantPrealerta: number = 0;
  public cantManifestado: string = '';
  public cantRetenido: number = 0;
  public cantTransferido: string = '';
  public cantDespachado :number = this.cantPrealerta - this.cantRetenido ;

  Guardado() {
    // window.alert("Se guardo el despacho exitosamente");
    var vMaster = campoMaster.values;
    var cliente = campoCliente.values;
    var vMaster = campoPrealerta.values;
    var vMaster = campoManifestado.values;
    var vMaster = campoRetenido.values;
    var vMaster = [(ngModel)]="cantTransferido".values;
    var vMaster = campoDespachado.values;

  }


  // vMaster='';
  // cliente='';
  // cantPrealerta='';
  // cantManifestado='';
  // cantRetenido='';
  // cantTransferido='';
  // cantDespachado= '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Te agrego un ejemplo sencillo de como hacer la relación del modelo con el formulario y la tabla:

**archivo .ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  // los datos se van guardando en un arreglo, el cual se usa para
  // desplegar la tabla
  personas:any[] = [];

  // los input del formulario se asocian con un modelo
  persona:any = {};


  guardar(){
    // se inserta el dato en el arreglo
    this.personas.push(this.persona);

    // se crea un nuevo objeto para almacenar nuevos datos
    this.persona = {};
  }
}
```

**archivo .html**

```
nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]="persona.nombre"/><br/>
direccion: <input type="text" name="direccion"[(ngModel)]="persona.direccion"/><br>
<input type="button" value="guardar" (click)="guardar()"/>

<h4>datos ingresados</h4>

<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let persona of personas">
    <td>{{persona.nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{persona.direccion}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Código stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qvreua?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)